# Access VBA outputto pdf "output to" prompt

Tags: ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2007, vba

I am getting a weird problem in Access 2007 SP3. When I export a report to pdf I get the "Output To" prompt which I don't want, is there anything in my code I am doing wrong?

```
OverViewFile = DLookup("ExportPath", "dbo_Defaults") & "PC" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & Format(Now(), "hhmm") & ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Rpt_ExportBPC", acFormatPDF, OverViewFile, False
```

If I've missed anything please let me know.

Comment: What do you get from `Debug.Print OverViewFile`?

Comment: Hi, nothing happens, it just runs it without doing anything?

Comment: Did you inspect the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window?  You can go there with Ctrl+g

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!! It says C:\program files\Folder\DataExport\PC2910131512.pdf which is correct

Comment: Do you have write permission in `C:\program files`?  I thought Windows discourages us from writing there.  I haven't actually tried in years though.

Comment: I do have permission to the Program Files directory I created a file manually in there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that prompt from Access 2007 SP3 when adapting your `OutputTo` with the name of my report object and giving it a valid file path for *OverViewFile*.  So I suspect your problem is due to *OverViewFile*; inspect the value of that string:

```vb
OverViewFile = DLookup("ExportPath", "dbo_Defaults") & "PC" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & Format(Now(), "hhmm") & ".pdf"
Debug.Print OverViewFile
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Rpt_ExportBPC", acFormatPDF, OverViewFile, False
```

You can view the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there).

Perhaps `DLookup` is returning Null.  You would then have a valid VBA string for *OverViewFile*, but it would not be a valid Windows path.

There is another issue with *OverViewFile* which probably doesn't contribute to the problem, but I'll suggest this because it's simpler and I think you actually want *hhnn* instead of *hhmm* in the file name (*n* represents minute; *m* represents month)

```vb
OverViewFile = DLookup("ExportPath", "dbo_Defaults") & "PC" & _
    Format(Now(), "ddmmyyhhnn") & ".pdf"
```

Comment: Just curious: Does `OutputTo` prompt if the file already exists? If so, then a mm vs. nn mixup might cause that.

Comment: It didn't prompt for me when the destination file existed.  Instead it silently replaced the old file.

Comment: Thanks for your help HansUp, the dlookup definitely is not null. Just found that it works from .mdb but not a .mde? I've also changed the hhmm to hhnn.

Comment: Just a though, do I need to enable any VBA references to get this to work?

Comment: `DoCmd` is a method of the application object.  So, if this were a references issue, I think you would have many more problems ... not limited to only `OutputTo`.